# How to access class value in a Matlab mex file?

Tags: c, matlab, class, mex

This is my simple dummy class using .m file in Matlab.

```
function obj = dummy(varargin)
  if nargin~=1
    error('nothing to do here')
    return
  end

  obj = init_fields;
  obj = class(obj, 'dummy');
  obj.file = varargin{1};

end

function obj = init_fields()
  obj.file = [];
end

>> a = dummy('file.name');
```

I can now access `a.file` in other .m function-files. e.g. `something = newfunction(a)`

But how can I access the value of obj.file in a C written MEX function (that I can fopen("file.name"))?

```
mxArray *pa;
mexPrintf("%s\n", mxGetFieldNameByNumber(prhs[0], 0));
pa = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0], 0, 0);
mexPrintf("%s\n", pa); /* this don't work */
mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 1, &pa, "disp"); /* this works * /
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As of R2014a, there are two API functions in the Matlab Matrix Library: `mxGetProperty` and `mxSetProperty`. (See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/access-data.html)) As long as your object is a simple value class with public properties, they should work. Otherwise you have to use `mexCallMATLAB` to access data.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way to access the class value in a MEX file.
My workaround is now to use a .m function as a wrapper

```
function out=dumdum(obj,cmd) 
    out=mexfnc(obj.file, cmd); 
end
```